# Rails Availability Query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a trainer model and a trainer_availabilities model which stores a start and end time for trainers. The trainer_availabilities belongs_to trainers.

I want to query the trainer_availabilties model and return all trainers available at a certain start and end time (I am using timestamps with timezone). I'll be sending in a start and end time as parameters.

What would be the best practice way to query this structure without having to load the entire trainer_availabilties table? Is there another best practice method that would include some self referencing to cut down on resources? The available table will obviously grow over time and become quite large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using below code. Suggestions for improvements welcome. I included parsing for those sending info from client side.

```
#parse dates
@start_time = DateTime.parse(params[:start_time])
@end_time = DateTime.parse(params[:end_time])

#convert to string
@start_time = @start_time.to_s
@end_time = @end_time.to_s


@trainer_avails = TrainerAvailability.where('start_time <= ? AND start_time < ? AND end_time >= ? AND end_time > ?', @start_time, @end_time, @end_time, @start_time)
```